# Execution of FOR EACH STATEMENT Trigger in Transaction Context

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, transactions

I'm planning to install a trigger on a table which is executed after every statement (`foreach`-statement).

But I'm not sure what statement exactly means. For example, if I do multiple inserts in one transaction, for example 1,000.

Will the trigger then be executed **one** time for a **thousand** times?

Comment: If one `INSERT` adds 1000 rows, that's one statement.  If you have 1000 `INSERT`s, that's 1000 statements.

Comment: @MatBailie yeah I know but I could imagine that the rules for transactions can be different I was just curios :)

Comment: Imagine the case that transactions meant it behaved differently. How would the trigger know when to run? At the end of the transaction? Now the logic inside the transaction can't know the result of the trigger. You'd have race conditions, and inconsistencies all over the place. From the perspective of all other processes, triggers are part of the insert; until the triggers have finished, neither has the insert (other processes never see the "incomplete" state). Useful reading for why this is relevant is on Atomic Actions specifically, and a database's ACID compliance in general.